# append a list from another class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to merge list of tuples from to different class.

I have a class parser, where the tuples will be merged. The class and corresponding function is defined as:

```
class parser():
    def __init__(self):
        self.booklist = []
    def parsing_write(self, filename):
        # print(self.booklist)
        datalist = []
        writer = BibTexWriter()
        writer.indent = '    '
        print(self.booklist)
        for ref in self.booklist:
            print(type(ref))
            datadict = dict((k, v) for k, v in
                            zip(self.entries, ref) if v is not None)
            datalist.append(datadict)
```

and in another function, I have done:

```
import pybib
class Window(Gtk.ApplicationWindow):
    def __init__(self, application, giofile=None):
        self.Parser = pybib.parser()

    def get_data(self, datalist):
        datatup = tuple([name] + [self.KeyEntry.get_text()] +
                        [self.all_fields[field].get_text() or None
                         for field in fields])
        print(type(datatup))
        print(type(self.Parser.booklist))
        self.Parser.booklist.append(datatup)
        print((self.Parser.booklist))
```

and I am expecting the `datatup` from `Class Window` will be appended to the `booklist` in `Class parser`. But it is not. 
So, just to show, the output from `parsing_write`'s `print(self.booklist)` 
is:

```
[('article', 'ebert2013', 'First-principles', 'Mankovsky, S.', None, '2013')]
```

and then, if I invoke `get_data`, I am getting result:

```
<class 'tuple'>
<class 'list'>
[('Article', 'key', None, 'au', None, None, None, None, None)]
```

But I am expecting this list to be append the list in `parsing_write`.

**N.B.** Please ignore the length of each list, as I have stripped them.

Comment: May I know the reason for the close vote? I may improve the question if I know the fault.

Answer (score 0):

In your Window class you didn't return the list so how can your parser know what you are trying to do? Just make a return statement to self.datatup and then pass the result of that method call to the class Parser and it should work.

```
import pybib
class Window(Gtk.ApplicationWindow):
    def __init__(self, application, giofile=None):
        self.Parser = pybib.parser()

    def get_data(self, datalist):
        self.datatup = tuple([name] + [self.KeyEntry.get_text()] +
                        [self.all_fields[field].get_text() or None
                         for field in fields])
        print(type(self.datatup))
        print(type(self.Parser.booklist))
        self.Parser.booklist.append(self.datatup)
        print((self.Parser.booklist))
        return(self.datatup)
```

Comment: If i am not missing anything, I just need to add  `return(self.datatup)` at the end of `get_data`. I tried that and its not working.

Comment: Did you instantiate the object and call your get method, store that in a variable and pass into parser obj method?

Comment: no...actually this is all I have done to update the booklist